# how to pass context outside stless and staful class flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use context in constant files e.g

```
class StatusCodes {  
    static Map<int, String> overTimeCancelResponse = {
    0: "OverTime request Cancel Successfully",
    1: "Error Cancelling OverTime Request",
  }; 
}

or 
   
   class StatusCodes {
   static Map<int, OverTimeResponses> overTimeResponse = {
   0: OverTimeResponses(
      "Overtime Request Submitted Successfully",
       Colours.green,
     ),
   };
}
```

I am using a language file to change eng to a different Language like this e.g

```
class StatusCodes {  
    static Map<int, String> overTimeCancelResponse = {
    0: S.0f(context).cancel_request,
    1: S.0f(context).error,
  }; 
}
```

but I am not been able to use context here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Map function function, pass the context through parameters and return your map

See the below code

```
class StatusCodes {
  Map<int, String> overTimeCancelResponse(BuildContext context) {
   return {
     0: "OverTime request Cancel Successfully", // you can pass a value with context here
     1: "Error Cancelling OverTime Request",
  };
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shouldn't, but if you "must" this is the closest you can get:

```
class StatusCodes {

    static Map<int, String> getOverTimeCancelResponse(BuildContext context) {
      // Do something with context
      // ....
      // build your new "overTimeCancelResponse"
      return newOverTimeCancelResponse;
    }
}
```

It is not possible to use `BuildContext` (or any other variable) in a static variable.

Comment: i tried to pass build context to function and try to get data inside function but nothing worked for me

Comment: Your comment doesn't say anything useful. It doesn't say what you tried to do nor what didn't work.